# How to update deprecated com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, android-httptransport

I have the follow object

```
HttpTransport t = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
```

but whole `AndroidHttp` class (`com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp`) is marked as deprecated.

I don't know what is the class that replaces this, using newer libraries.

How could I replace this obsolete call?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/blob/master/google-http-client-android/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/extensions/android/http/AndroidHttp.java) tells us that prior to Gingerbread the HttpURLConnection implementation was buggy and Apache HTTP Client was preferred.

However this has been fixed for newer versions and now `new NetHttpTransport()` can be used directly. So just use: `HttpTransport t = new NetHttpTransport();` and you should be fine.

This is also what `newCompatibleTransport` does behind the curtain:

`public static HttpTransport newCompatibleTransport() {
    return AndroidUtils.isMinimumSdkLevel(9) ? new NetHttpTransport() : new ApacheHttpTransport();
}`